# How to create merge request with optionally GitLab CI/CD manual pipeline?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, cicd

I have defined pipeline in GitLab CI/CD like below:

```
build app:
  stage: build
  variables:
    APP_NAME: app
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      changes:
        - $APP_NAME/**/*
      when: manual
  extends: .build

deploy app:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    APP_NAME: app
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      changes:
        - $APP_NAME/**/*
      when: manual
  extends: .deploy
```

When I want to merge code to master, both build and deploy stage must be manually run and they must succeed. However, I would like sometimes merge code to master after only when build stage will succeed and do not run deploy stage. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes I think it’s possible.

I think if you change your deploy stage to check for another gitlab variable (one that you set dynamically or within a schedule) like: … TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $DEPLOY == “true”

Then that job should only occur when a $DEPLOY variable has been set to “true” which won’t happen when you simply merge to main, unless you set it.

Then you can trigger a new pipeline run manually and add the variable and it will deploy.